# Laravel seeder for email template settings

Tags: php, laravel, seeder

This is my Laravel seeder for two database tables. I need to make this seeder more efficient and optimized. How can this be achieved? I would appreciate some tips.

```
$userId = User::first()->id;

        // information of email template variable
        $emailTemplateVariables = [
            'user-create' => ['module' => 1, 'module_event' => 1, 'value' => ['USER_NAME', 'USER_EMAIL']],
            'user-deactive' => ['module' => 1, 'module_event' => 7, 'value' => ['USER_NAME', 'USER_EMAIL']],
            'purchase-order-create' => ['module' => 5, 'module_event' => 1, 'value' => ['ORDER_NO', 'PRODUCT_NAME', 'PURCHASE_DATE', 'PRODUCT_QUANTITY', 'ORDER_PRICE', 'SUPPLIER', 'SUPPLIER_INVOICE_NO', 'WAREHOUSE', 'STORE_NAME', 'STORE_ADDRESS', 'STORE_PHONE', 'STORE_WEBSITE', 'STORE_EMAIL']]
        ];

        collect($emailTemplateVariables)->each(function ($templateVariableItem, $slug) use ($userId) {
            $templateVariableIds = collect($templateVariableItem['value'])
                ->map(function ($value) use ($userId) {
                    return EmailTemplateVariable::updateOrCreate(
                        ['variable_key' => $value],
                        ['created_by' => $userId]
                    )->id;
                })->toArray();

            EmailTemplateSetting::create([
                'slug' => $slug,
                'module_id' => $templateVariableItem['module'],
                'module_event_id' => $templateVariableItem['module_event'],
                'template_variable_ids' => json_encode($templateVariableIds),
                'created_by' => $userId,
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: Your question runs the risk of _not getting reviewed_ because it lacks any decent context. Did you read up on how to ask a good question? See: [Help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). We'll be more willing to put effort into reviewing your code, if you show a bit of effort on your part. Also, don't forget [there's an answer to your question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522586/optimize-laravel-db-seeder) you didn't respond to.

Answer (score 2):

To improve your Laravel seeders, focus on grouping and using connections between data. Here's how to do it:

1. **Batch Insert**: Instead of adding `EmailTemplateVariable` one at a time, add them in groups if they are not there already.
2. **Use Relationships**: If `EmailTemplateSetting` and `EmailTemplateVariable` are connected, use this connection to bind variables instead of setting IDs manually.

Here's a way to rework your seeder:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\EmailTemplateVariable;
use App\Models\EmailTemplateSetting;

class EmailTemplateSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $userId = User::first()->id;

        $emailTemplateVariables = [
            ...
        ];

        // Fetch all existing variables to minimize database queries.
        $existingVariables = EmailTemplateVariable::all()->pluck('id', 'variable_key');

        foreach ($emailTemplateVariables as $slug => $item) {
            // Instead of one by one, add your `EmailTemplateVariable` in groups if they are not already there.
            $variableIds = collect($item['value'])->map(function ($variable) use (&$existingVariables, $userId) {
                if (!$existingVariables->has($variable)) {
                    $created = EmailTemplateVariable::create(['variable_key' => $variable, 'created_by' => $userId]);
                    $existingVariables[$variable] = $created->id;
                }
                return $existingVariables[$variable];
            })->toArray();

            // If there's a link between `EmailTemplateSetting` and `EmailTemplateVariable`
            // use it to connect variables instead of giving IDs yourself.
            EmailTemplateSetting::create([
                'slug' => $slug,
                'module_id' => $item['module'],
                'module_event_id' => $item['module_event'],
                'template_variable_ids' => json_encode($variableIds),
                'created_by' => $userId,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Consider using arrow functions

While it likely won't lead to much in terms of efficiency, the syntax can be simplified. When a closure/function only has one expression then it can often be converted to [an arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php), which eliminates the need for a `use` statement since there is no separate scope.

For example- the nested callback passed to `map()`:

> ```
>           function ($value) use ($userId) {
>                return EmailTemplateVariable::updateOrCreate(
>                    ['variable_key' => $value],
>                    ['created_by' => $userId]
>                )->id;
>            }
> ```

Converting this to an arrow function gives:

```
        fn($value) => EmailTemplateVariable::updateOrCreate(
            ['variable_key' => $value],
            ['created_by' => $userId]
        )->id
```

## Eliminate single use variables

The variable `$templateVariableIds` is only used once after it is assigned. Perhaps the value was inspected during debugging but otherwise there is not much point to assign it a variable - the value can be substituted in the one place it is used.

I haven't tested it but conceivably the last `collect()` block could be simplified to this:

```
collect($emailTemplateVariables)->each(fn($templateVariableItem, $slug) => EmailTemplateSetting::create([
    'slug' => $slug,
    'module_id' => $templateVariableItem['module'],
    'module_event_id' => $templateVariableItem['module_event'],
    'template_variable_ids' => json_encode(
        collect($templateVariableItem['value'])
            ->map(fn($value) => EmailTemplateVariable::updateOrCreate(
                ['variable_key' => $value],
                ['created_by' => $userId]
            )->id)->toArray()
    ),
    'created_by' => $userId,
]));
```